# how to compile Shadowsocks source code on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

The Shadowsocks source code is here. -> [source code](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android).

I download android studio 3.6, which is the latest version. I also cloned the latest source code of Shadowsocks code.

When I compile this project, I got errors, the last error is

```
This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer.
```

Is there any guide for compiles the Shadowsocks source code?

Comment: Install Android Studio 4.1, or downgrade the plugin version, or simply build with Gradle.

Comment: it's Android studio plugin, not android studio

Comment: the latest android studio version is 3.6

Comment: a) this makes no difference, as it always demands the same version number and b) this is not the case, because latest version and latest stable version is not the same.